# Match strings with dynamic format in R

Tags: r

I want to check if a column has no header for an input data frame.
The problem appears when I use `fread(filename)` that change the missing header to a default name "V+Number of column"(ex: V1 for the first column, V2, etc). I read the documentation of that function and doesn't seem to be able to change that default value for the headers.
So taking that in mind i want to take all columns that contains `V + number` as missing headers. It will be very helpful if someone explains how to do something like this:

`if(string == (V1, V2, ... VN)){ do something }`
Like compare if a String is equal to 'V' plus integer.

Comment: A am not sure if thats what you want but you could use `paste`. `if(string %in% paste0("V",1:length(string))) {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can obtain all colums Vx values using str_extract, from stringr package I think.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(colnames(myDataFrame), "V\\d*")
```

Example:

```
dt <- data.frame("aaaa" = c(1:5), "V2" = c(6:10), "V3123" = c(11:15), "V455" = c(16:20))
str_extract(colnames(dt), "V\\d*")
```

> "NA"    "V2"    "V3123" "V455"

Then you can do what you need with, with de columns names

Comment: I apologize for the delay, this works properly! Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

How is this? I don't exactly know what you want to do with the missing column names; if you want to replace them with blanks or record their positions, adjust the print statements accordingly to make a vector with, for example, all `i` where `It's missing`.

```
x <- data.frame(A=1,B=2,V3=3,V4=4,C=5)    
z <- names(x)

for(i in 1:length(z)){
  if(z[i]==paste0("V", i)){
    print("It's missing")
  } else {
    print("Not missing")
  }
}
```